# Need help adding methods in main class

Tags: java

Hello I'm working on a project for my java class, I'm supposed to write a code for a Algebra tutor that goes like this:

> Write a program with a that displays a randomly generated problem that asks the user to solve for the y variable, takes input from the user, and prints "correct" if the user answered correctly and prints "incorrect" if not. Your main should give one problem and then exit. Use one or more methods to produce this behavior.

This is regarding the formula mx + b. So here is what I have so far, and works!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        double min_value = -100;
        double max_value = 100;
        double m_value = (int)(Math.random()*((max_value-min_value)+1))+min_value;
        double x_value = (int)(Math.random()*((max_value-min_value)+1))+min_value;
        double b_value = (int)(Math.random()*((max_value-min_value)+1))+min_value;
        System.out.println("Given: ");
        System.out.println("m = " + m_value);
        System.out.println("x = " + x_value);
        System.out.println("b = " + b_value);
        System.out.print("What is the value of y? ");
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user_answer = "";
        user_answer = user_input.next();
        int correct_answer = (int)m_value * (int)x_value + (int)b_value;
        if (user_answer.equals(correct_answer))
            System.out.println("You are correct!");
        else
            System.out.print("Sorry, that is incorrect. ");
        System.out.println("The answer is " + correct_answer);
    }
}
```

so even tho the output is correct, I need to break down the code into smaller methods, this is where Im getting confused on how to take a piece of that code and put it in another method that once it runs it calls for that method too and gives me the same output. I been ready the material given but the more I read it the more confuse I get. If anybody has any ideas or suggestions please let me know any info will be really appreciate. Thank you

Comment: I'd say you don't need to.  The problem statement says "use one or more methods".  You've done that, since `main` is a method.  Note that there are a few issues with your code.  Not least is that you're comparing a `String` to an integer to determine whether the answer is correct.  The result of that comparison will always be `false`.  Also, always use `{` and `}` with `if` and `else`, otherwise you can get bugs where a line of code _looks like_ it's inside the branch, but it actually isn't.

Comment: I'd ask the instructor for clarification, frankly.  Maybe they meant "one or more methods in addition to `main`", but it's not clear.  There's honestly no good reason to break this particular method into several.

Comment: ok I will add the { } totally forgot, thanks!

Comment: although main counts as a method, the instructor wants me to create one more to break down the coding into "smaller" parts?

Comment: Well, theoretically, you could split it wherever you like.  But maybe the logic that checks whether the answer is correct and prints the output would be a good candidate for being moved to another method.  You could pass the correct answer and the user's guess as arguments to the method.

Comment: how can I convert the String that I get from the user to an int? I tried to do the same as the doubles to int but from String to int is not working.

Comment: Ok I will try to move to another method the logic whether the answer is correct or incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick rundown on methods, so it's not completely done yet. Ask, if you need more help! Good luck on your homework and on becoming one of the beast developers!

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 1; // give a value of 1

    methodTwo(a); // sending the int a into another method

    }

    // Here's method number two
    static void methodTwo (int a) { // it gives a's type and value

        System.out.println(a); //Gives out a's value, which is 1
    }

}
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you Miska I do have a question, why here is the method static void and the other code below there is one that is private static void? Thank you again this is my third day learning java lol and its a lot to take in but I feel really motivated to learn, thanks for the positive energy.

Comment: Nice catch! I left it empty without a reason, just used an easy example off the web haha. You can actually put multiple different things in front of the method. `Public` methods are used, when you want to call the method from the different class, you can only have one method called methodTwo, if it's public. `Private` methods can only be called inside the same class as it appears. `Nothing in front` means it can be called inside a package the class is at. `Protected` method can be called inside a package plus subclasses in and outside of the package.

Comment: If that sounds confusing, don't worry. You're now learning methods, not classes or packages :D You'll learn more about them soon, I'm sure. The most used ones are  `public` and `private` and I suggest using them most of the time. As I said, my `nothing` was just copy-paste lol. Some teacher I am... :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you've solved the problem correctly, you are using one or more methods, but perhaps what you trying to do is a common code refactor called the [extract method / extract function refactor](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method) Executing this type of refactor leads to much more readable and maintainable code, and is easy to do.

As a starter, identify code that repeats or looks similar, in your case, the following lines look ripe for extract method:

```
double m_value = (int)(Math.random()*((max_value-min_value)+1))+min_value;
double x_value = (int)(Math.random()*((max_value-min_value)+1))+min_value;
double b_value = (int)(Math.random()*((max_value-min_value)+1))+min_value;
```

Notice that the RHS of each line is identicial, so we can replace the explicit code with a method call like this:

```
double m_value = getRandomDoubleBetween(max_value, min_value);
double x_value = getRandomDoubleBetween(max_value, min_value);
double b_value = getRandomDoubleBetween(max_value, min_value);

private double getRandomDoubleBetween(double max_value, double min_value) {
     return (int)(Math.random()*((max_value-min_value)+1))+min_value;
 }
```

You can identify other areas of code that either contain repetition or perhaps some hard to understand code that would be more understandable if it was extracted into a method that had a name that reveals what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this part I kind of thought there was a way of not repeating myself I will study this for sure, Im really new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

Please review this, you are comparing `string` with `integer`,

```
if (user_answer.equals(correct_answer))
```

This may help you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        double min_value = -100;
        double max_value = 100;

        double m_value = generateRandom(max_value, min_value);
        double x_value = generateRandom(max_value, min_value);
        double b_value = generateRandom(max_value, min_value);

        System.out.println("Given: ");
        System.out.println("m = " + m_value);
        System.out.println("x = " + x_value);
        System.out.println("b = " + b_value);

        checkAnswer(m_value, x_value, b_value);         
    }

    private static void checkAnswer(double m_value, double x_value, double b_value) {

        System.out.print("What is the value of y? ");

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user_answer = "";
        user_answer = user_input.next();

        int correct_answer = (int) m_value * (int) x_value + (int) b_value;

        if (user_answer.equals(String.valueOf(correct_answer))) {
            System.out.println("You are correct!");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Sorry, that is incorrect. ");
            System.out.println("The answer is " + correct_answer);
            user_input.close();
        }
    }
    static int generateRandom(double max_value, double min_value) {

        return (int) ((int) (Math.random() * ((max_value - min_value) 
+ 1)) + min_value);

    }
}
```

Comment: ok I can see a lot of things I didnt need in my code like the imports at the top, the string with the int in the if statement, i have to look at it for a while to kind of understand I think the more familiar I get with it, it will be better, thank you all for helping me